# Given the density function, calculate the expected value $E(X)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, density-function

> Given the density function$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{x^2}{2}&\mbox{if }0\leq x<1\\
> -x^2+3x-\frac{3}{2}&\mbox{if }1\leq x<2\\
> \frac{(3-x)^2}{2}&\mbox{if }2\leq x<3\\
> 0&\mbox{else}\end{cases}$$
>
> Calculate $E(X)$

Can you please tell me if I do it correct? Because I would do it like that in the exam and I hope it's good:

$$E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x) \;dx = \int_{0}^{1} x\frac{x^2}{2}\;dx + \int_{1}^{2} x(-x^2+3x-\frac{3}{2})\;dx + \int_{2}^{3} x\frac{(3-x)^2}{2}\;dx$$

I leave further calculation away to keep it short, just this part I'm not sure if it's fine like that?

Comment: Yup. Just use the definition of expected value for RVs with given densities, and the fact that the density is piecewise defined, so you can break up the integral accordingly. Remember, basic probability is often just adding a few new concepts then doing basic calculus!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Seek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Absolutely_continuous_case) and you shall find. Anyways, yeah, you are doing that correctly.

Comment: Also, (discrete-mathematics) tag is clearly misused here.